tun/tap always linkdown and no packets arrives
I'm trying to use bmv2(a software switch) to control the whole traffic flowing from the host to the Internet. I've learnt that tap can help to realize it.
I use tunctl to generate a tap. However, the tap0 keeps linkdown while I use ip link set tap0 up.
I use ip route add and set tap0 as the default route. However, I can't receive any packets on tap0.
I'm doing this on Ubuntu 20. What's wrong with my setting? Could someone give me some advice.

Do you have some software connected to the backend? The tap0 interface you see is just “one end of the network cable”.

I'm not understanding how to connected to the backend ( sorry about that I was poor at this). I only know that "a tap interface is actually working only when there's an userspace program handling it (eg: QEMU, OpenVPN, openssh ...)", but I don't know how to connected.
And does a python scripts can be a software connected to the backend?
Or why did wireshark catch nothing, even though I did't have some software connected to the backend.

As long as no process is attached, the interface will be NO-CARRIER => operstate DOWN. For example (install socat) if you run socat -u TUN,tun-name=tap0,tun-type=tap /dev/null the interface will get a carrier and change to operstate UP (not that it will be useful alone: socat doesn't include a network stack. It could still be used as conduit for a tunnel). Just figure out how to configure bvm2 to attach to the tap0 interface (if it can at all).

Thanks! I have learnt a lot. I would be back if I succeed!
